# pass query result through to another page php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP so keep that in mind. I've got my page working very well but I'm having an issue with getting a pass through variable to work.

```
                $sql = "    SELECT  vehicles.VYear, vmake.VMake, vmodel.VModel, vehicles.VTrim, vehicles.VehicleID 

                            FROM    vehicles 
                                    INNER JOIN mycars.vmake ON vehicles.VMakeID = vmake.VMakeID
                                    INNER JOIN mycars.vmodel ON vehicles.VModelID = vmodel.VModelID

                            WHERE vehicles.VCurrentlyOwn = '1'";

                $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

                echo "<table>";
                echo "  <tr>
                            <th>Year</th>
                            <th>Make</th>
                            <th>Model</th>
                            <th>Trim</th>
                        </tr>";

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                    $year   =   $row['VYear'];
                    $make   =   $row['VMake'];
                    $model  =   $row['VModel'];
                    $trim   =   $row['VTrim'];
                    $vid    =   $row['VehicleID'];

                    echo "  <tr>
                                <td style='width: 50px;'>".$year."</td>
                                <td style='width: 175px;'>".$make."</td>
                                <td style='width: 200px;'>".$model."</td>
                                <td style='width: 100px;'>".$trim."</td>
                                <td style='width: 25px;'>".'<a href="mycarsprofile.php?id=$vid">+</a>'."</td>
                            </tr>";

                }

                echo "</table>"
```

This code works fine when you have the line:

href="mycarsprofile.php?id=214"

with just a number there after id. However, I want it to populate that id with the VehicleID ($vid) from the query before it. I've tried putting in the php to echo the variable but it just says undefined variable on the linked page. I've been searching the ineternet for a while and still nothing. This should be simple. I want each row in the results to have a different ID linked to them, that's why I think I need to keep the variable in the while loop. But, it seems as though no matter what I try it's just not working.

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From this:**

```
echo "  <tr>
            <td style='width: 50px;'>".$year."</td>
            <td style='width: 175px;'>".$make."</td>
            <td style='width: 200px;'>".$model."</td>
            <td style='width: 100px;'>".$trim."</td>
            <td style='width: 25px;'>".'<a href="mycarsprofile.php?id=$vid">+</a>'."</td>
          </tr>";
```

**To this**

```
echo "  <tr>
            <td style='width: 50px;'>".$year."</td>
            <td style='width: 175px;'>".$make."</td>
            <td style='width: 200px;'>".$model."</td>
            <td style='width: 100px;'>".$trim."</td>
            <td style='width: 25px;'><a href='mycarsprofile.php?id=". $vid ."'>+</a></td>
          </tr>";
```

Just edit this line into your code:

`<td style='width: 25px;'><a href='mycarsprofile.php?id=". $vid ."'>+</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have some concatenation issue.

```
echo "  <tr>
     <td style='width: 50px;'>".$year."</td>
     <td style='width: 175px;'>".$make."</td>
     <td style='width: 200px;'>".$model."</td>
     <td style='width: 100px;'>".$trim."</td>
     <td style='width: 25px;'>".'<a href="mycarsprofile.php?id='.$vid.'">+</a>'."</td>  
                                                               ^^^^^^^^
     </tr>";
```